# Gson - security issue?

Tags: java, security, gson, owasp

I'm trying to investigate a security issue with serialization / deserialization of data based on [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Deserialization_of_untrusted_data) from OWASP.  My question is if Gson follows the recommended items to prevent security issues in deserialization / prevents them from occurring.

I'm also wondering since it refers to untrusted data, if having ssl pinning on the client and API would prevent this completely, if Gson wasn't secure?

Comment: Is your data trusted or untrusted? SSL has nothing to do with it.

Comment: ssl pinning has to do with trusting your source of data. by pinning our client to our api, then we should be able to trust all data returned by the endpoint with that specific certificate.

Comment: Not really. If you are getting your data from an untrusted source, like a user, or a partner org, it doesn't matter if you are transmitting it securely, it is still untrusted.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning#What_Is_Pinning.3F